# Apply google app script function to range of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a funktion, that replace solved formulas by values, and not solved formulas its just refresh. But I need this funktion to apply it for fixed range (B2:G) of cells on several sheets. Please help to solve it or just say where its better to search answer?

```
function testfindfunc1() 
{
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('18869')
  var targetrow = 37;
  var targetcell = 2;
  var result = ss1.getRange(targetrow, targetcell);
  //var formula1 = result.getFormula();
  var findVal = ss1.getRange(targetrow, targetcell).getValue();

  if( findVal == ('#N/A') || findVal == ('Loading...')) 
  {
   var rangeToCopy = ss1.getRange(targetrow, targetcell);
   rangeToCopy.copyTo(ss1.getRange(targetrow, targetcell));
  } 
  else 
  {
   result.setValue(findVal);
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the point of copying a cell over itself?

Comment: Cells contain formula with IMPORTXML funktion, and they are solving very slowly - about some days, because of the limited number of incoming requests to the site. I want to create trigger, which every 30 or 15 minutes will replace solved formulas by values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a value on a cell will remove the formula on it. First select the `range` you want and then `loop` through the range checking each cell of it for whether formula has executed or not.

```
function testfindfunc1() 
{
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('18869');
  var range = ss1.getRange('B2:G10');
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {

      var currentValue = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
        if( currentValue == "#N/A"|| currentValue == "Loading...") 
        {
          // if formula has not exicuted
         // do nothing, leave the cell as it is
        }
       else
       {
         //remove the formula and set the value
          range.getCell(i,j).setValue(currentValue);
       }
    }
  }  
}
```

Edit : **Much faster method**

```
function testfindfunc2() 
{
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss1.getRange('B2:G100');
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var valuesToSet = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {

      var currentValue = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
        if( currentValue == "#N/A"|| currentValue == "Loading...") 
        {
          // if formula has not exicuted
         // do nothing, leave the cell as it is
        }
       else
       {
         //remove the formula and set the value
         //range.getCell(i,j).setValue(currentValue);
         // store in an array
          valuesToSet.push([range.getCell(i,j),currentValue])
       }
    }
  }
  //setting values
  for(var rng in valuesToSet)
  {
    valuesToSet[rng][0].setValue(valuesToSet[rng][1]);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, iJay! Its work perfect! But is it should be that the function is running slowly? About 2 minutes for range of 4 cells.

Comment: It might be slow coz two `for loops`, but it shouldn't that much slow for 4 cells :O

Comment: Yes, I think same! And for larger range after 6 minutes of running return error: Exceeded maximum execution time

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you very much!